# Is it possible to build an in-line stereo amplifier for piezo contact mics (stereo pair) with 2.5v plug-in power?

Tags: microphone

From one idea to the next, here's the back story:
I'm currently taking an interest in sound design, and read an article about making sound effects from recording via contact microphones. I already have a portable stereo recorder which is the [Zoom H2n](https://www.zoom-na.com/products/field-video-recording/field-recording/zoom-h2n-handy-recorder), which has a line/mic input (which is stereo), which has 2.5v plug-in power which I can switch on if required.

Now I want to make my own stereo piezo mic and plug it into my recorder, but do you think I need a pre-amp when the Zoom h2N has it's own mic gain control? I gather the impedence of piezos is as much as 50KOhm and would be too quiet if wired directly to a line/mic input. The ones at Maplin (where I might source my components) are 450Ohm-800Ohm.  If I need the extra preamp then I'd like to see if I can use the plug-in power from my recorder to power a home-made stereo preamp. I've seen the [Alex Rice preamp circuit design](https://www.zachpoff.com/diy-resources/alex-rice-piezo-preamplifier/), but this is made for 48v Phantom power not 2.5v. I presume I will need a complete exchange of components as well as adapt it for stereo if don't just make two of them....so, is 2.5v enough to amplify a piezo contact mic signal?

For the record I'm no good at designing circuits, I'm just good at assembling them.

Comment: It says LINE IN with a microphone symbol next to it. I presume but not sure it handles both and intelligently senses what level the input is. I looked through the manual thoroughly but it doesn't cover that level of detail. This is bit electronical, I'm quite new to stackexchange, I joined stack overflow first and music practice and theory. Hoping that some sound-recording enthusiasts have already attempted my idea. I'd just like to this in-line without using a battery or other separate power source. Is it cool to just copy my question over to the electronics one or does it need to be moved?

Comment: "It says LINE IN with a microphone symbol next to it. I presume but not sure it handles both and intelligently senses what level the input is." I think that's right. "Is it cool to just copy my question over to the electronics one or does it need to be moved?" I THINK so. But I've never tried before.

Comment: I'm not confident enough in this answer to call it an answer, but I don't think amplification is the issue here; impedance matching is. You should be able to get by with an impedance-matching transformer. Contact mics are often used for pickups, and are very close to a Hi-Z input; a direct box for connecting guitars to line inputs would likely work. FWIW I field-record contact mics into a Tascam GT-R1 for this very reason - it's a handheld guitar recorder.